# Level statistics of many body localization

Tags: quantum-mechanics, condensed-matter, many-body, quantum-statistics, disorder

I was calculating some Hamiltonian's spectrum statistics. Namely, I calculated the Hamiltonian's eigenvalues and sorted them in an ascending order: $E_1,E_2,E_3...E_N$. The quantity I calculated is r, which is defined as follows:

$$\delta_n = E_{n+1}-E_{n}, $$

$$r_n = \frac{\min(\delta_n,\delta_{n+1})}{\max(\delta_n,\delta_{n+1})}.$$

If the Hamiltonian is an ergodic one, the matrix would be a Gaussian Orthogonal Ensemble and the mean of $r_n$ would be approximately 0.529. If the Hamiltonian exhibit many body localization the mean of $r_n$ would approximate 0.386. The probability distribution will only be as described under thermodynamic limit. With finite size systems, there would be a smooth transition between these two extremals when passing through many body localization transition. One then needs to resort to finite size scaling to determine the transition point.

My question is, what does it mean to have an average value of $r_n$ greater than 0.529? When I was calculating some model I devised(which I can not be too specific about, sorry for the trouble), the mean value of $r_n$ kept increasing beyond 0.529 as I keep increasing the interaction strength. So I am wondering if there are any physical upper bound on the mean value of $r_n$.

Edit:The system that I considered is a Floquet system, i.e. a system whose Hamiltonian is periodic in time. I calculated the Floquet operator:

$$U = \mathcal{T}\exp[-i\int_0^TH(t)dt]$$

and obtained its eigenvalues, which can be written as $e^{-i\epsilon_i T}$, $\epsilon_i$ is defined as quasienergy. The quasienergies are defined modulo $2\pi/T$. In my calculation their values are restricted in $[-\pi,\pi]$. I then use the quasienergies thus obtained to calculate the level statistics.

Would it be this non-uniqueness in the definition of quasi-energies that lead to the average of r greater than 0.529? If so, how could one circumvent such ambiguities and obtain the correct result? What other consequences would this non-uniqueness cause?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not too familiar with the exact details, but $\langle r\rangle \gtrsim 0.53$ is completely fine and expected in certain situations. In fact, $\langle r\rangle \simeq 0.60$ for Hamiltonians that behave like members of the GUE, and $\langle r\rangle \simeq 0.67$ for Hamiltonians that behave like members of the GSE.

If the value of $\langle r\rangle$ increases as your system's interaction parameter is increased, this might signal that the Hamiltonian associated with your system is transitioning from the GOE to the GUE.

As for the physical reason that such an increase occurs, I could not comment on this without knowing more about the system in question. It could be that an additional symmetry is added to the system as your parameter is increased, or it could be some reason that is entirely beyond me.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. As far as I know, <r> = 0.53 would correspond to the Hamiltonian being ergodic and satisfy eigenstate thermalization hypothesis. Could you provide some information what <r>=0.60 and <r>=0.67 correspond to? Like what kind of physical system would have such a level statistics?